# Using an Excel macro to query a spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2003

So I have some data in some spreadsheets and I've found that for all the macros and filtering and forumlas I've written to simplify it and narrow it down to what I want, it would have been much easier to just write some SQL against a few tables.

I guess I'm wondering: is it possible to have a macro in a workbook that queries data in some sheets and then populates another sheet with the result set? If so, how would I do it?

(It is Excel 2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a macro for this.

Go to `DATA-> Import External Data -> Import Data` then basically follow the prompts.  You may need to make a new data connection, (`New Source` at the bottom) but once connected you can write queries natively in Excel.

I'm guessing someone familiar with DBs would be able to figure it out pretty quickly.  If not, [here's a tutorial.](http://www.nickhodge.co.uk/pre2007/gui/datamenu/importexternal.htm)

Comment: Awesome! This looks like it might work for me. Only other thing to add is that the source file needs to have the data saved in a List (or maybe something else) or Excel will complain there's no tables.

Comment: Yeah, and if you are doing complicated logic Excel can also read from a view (i.e. if it is easier to put the logic in SQL than in Excel).

Comment: Here's the link to define table names on Excel ranges: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/t0006375.htm

Comment: @JNK: ...So... do these queries normally run so sloooooooow?

Comment: @Frustrated - Like all things SQL, it depends a lot on the table setup, query itself, version, yadda yadda yadda.

Comment: @JNK: Hmm ok now it ran in seconds. It seems like it either runs quickly, or Excel locks up forever (earlier, the query ran all through lunch so I had to kill it when I came back, now it only took seconds).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - It may be caching - SQL caches the query plan and relevant results.  If it was a similar query it will run much quicker the second go-around.

Comment: @JNK: I am not sure, I just opened the query editor and then immediately closed it - no changes, didn't save anythying. My system was thrashing pretty hard for a while and even though now it's stopped Excel is not responsive. Could it have anything to do with the fact that the source data is in the same file as the worksheet with the results (but on different worksheets)?

Comment: @Frustrated - Maybe.  It makes logical sense as Excel is reading from and writing to the same file, but sending to and fetching from SQL in between.

Comment: @JNK: Yeah, I guess I'll have to create a separate file for results. But overall it seems to work. Most of the time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a macro when you can simply query the excel file like this:

```
SELECT Column1, Cloumn2, Column3
FROM [SheetName$Range] 
WHERE Condition
```

Example:

```
SELECT ProductID, Qty, Price
FROM [SheetName$A10:C21] 
WHERE ProductID = 545
```

Comment: Does this work in Excel 2003? Just for the heck of it, I tried entering the formula `=select *
from [Sheet1!A1:B3]` into a cell on a worksheet (the range shown is valid) and Excel keeps giving an error saying "That name is not valid" and highlighting `[Sheet1`. Is there some other trick to this? I'm guessing you didn't actually mean for this to be a formula, maybe done in VBA?